Take elements of a list up to and including the first value that satisfies some predicate in Haskell
Given a predicate p, takeWhile p xs gives you the longest prefix of elements satisfying p. How can I get the shortest prefix containing an element that satisfies p?

What if no element satisfies the list?

If no element satisfies the predicate, it seems the desirable behavior is to return the entire (possibly infinite) list, as both your solution and @Ry-'s second version do below.

break, which splits a list on the first match, seems like a good starting point:
cutAfter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
cutAfter p xs = case break p xs of
    (start, mid : _) -> Just (start ++ [mid])
    _ -> Nothing

It also seems like a plausible choice to want a list that doesn’t contain a matching element to be taken in its entirety:
cutAfter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
cutAfter p xs =
    let (start, end) = break p xs
    in start ++ take 1 end

This option is nice because it’s more efficient and lazy – no need to find the match before using the list.

Ah your second answer is pretty much exactly what I was looking for!

We can use explicit recursion:
cutAfter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
cutAfter p = go
  where
    go [] = []
    go (x : xs)
      | p x = [x]
      | otherwise = x : go xs
If the list does not contain any element that satisfies the predicate p, it will return the entire list. So it just keeps yielding elements until (and including) the first element that satisfies the predicate.
This can also be done with a foldr-pattern:
cutAfter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
cutAfter p = foldr (\x -> if p x then const [x] else (x :)) []
